# Counting problem: Numbers of 10 digits that don't use every digit from 0 to 9.

Tags: combinatorics

Let X be the set of 10-digit numbers that do not contain all digits 0 through 9 in their decimal representation and do not begin with 0. How many elements does the set X have?

I think this should be done by counting principle. So I have 10 spots, and 10 options for each spot. However, the first number can't be 0, so the first spot has 9 options.

9 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 9

I think the 10th spot only have 9 options since I can't repeat one number (the representation doesn't have all the digits).

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you figure out how many such number DO HAVE every digit from $0$ to $9$ and the total number of 10-digit numbers?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework problems and which show absolutely no effort.  Have you tried anything at all?  People will meet you half way if you show some effort.

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, that was added after my first comment (though I should have seen it before the second).  Do you feel it reflects an honest effort?  If so, you should answer it...or, I could.  Either way.

Comment: @BelisaDi  the hint from Dave Renfro is spot on.  This is the sort of problem that is most easily attacked from the opposite direction.  Start from the total number and subtract off the ones that use each digit.  As a hint for the latter:  there would be $10!$ numbers which use each digit except for the fact that we can't start with $0$.  Can you see how to correct for that?

Comment: @lulu Judging from my own experience with high school students, yes, that's about as much effort as many of them will put into any one exercise unless someone sits down with them.

Comment: @Arthur Ok.  I'll work with the OP, if they are so inclined.

Comment: @BelisaDi  Any thoughts on the hint?

Comment: @BelisaDi Your counting is a little bit off. The last $9$ that you have to ensure that there is some repetition, well, if there is already repetition somewhere else in the number by the time you get there, there won't be any restrictions at all, and you have ten options instead of nine. Taking this into account correctly is a bit difficult, and I would suggest you instead start over with the approach outlined by Dave above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $10^{10}$ strings of length $10$ over the alphabet $\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$, and exactly $10!$ of these use all $10$ letters of the given alphabet. From the remaining $10^{10}-10!$ strings we should exclude all that have $0$ as first digit. By symmetry this amounts to ${1\over10}$ of all remaining strings. The number $N$ of admissible strings therefore is given by
$$N={9\over10}\bigl(10^{10}-10!\bigr)=8\,996\,734\,080\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments an easier approach is to count the $10$-digit sequences that use every digit from $0$ to $9$ or whose first digit is $0$.
There are $10!$ sequences that use every digit from $0$ to $9$.

There are $10^9$ sequences whose first digit is $0$ and from these, $9!$ use every digit from $0$ to $9$.
Therefore in total the sequences that satisfy either of the properties are $10^9-9!+10!=10^9+9\cdot9!$

Therefore there are $10^{10}-10^9-9\cdot9!=9\cdot(10^9-9!)$ elements in $X$